# How to show popup on startup activity in android application?

Tags: android, email, android-activity

How to show popup on startup activity in android application?

I want to show a `dialog popup` with a `textbox` which will `take up a name and email id from user` when `application is open first time`.?

Once name and emailid textbox is filled up by user and click on submit these values should go to `admin@mymail.com`

> my problem is on start up i'm binding webview also 
>       `mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);`

so because of that popup does not work properly or sometimes popup appears but webview does not render

`showdialog box code`

```
protected void showInputDialog() {

        // get prompts.xml view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView
                .findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        resultText.setText("Hello, " + editText.getText());
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Do you want to send the email or to remove it from an `EditText`?

Comment: issue is I want to show one popup with textbox.
once user enter his name and email click on submit it should go to admin@mymail.com

Comment: that's not an issue, that's a requirement.

Comment: check an updated question

Comment: my problem is on start up i'm binding webview also 
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

so because of that popup does not work properly or sometimes popup appears but webview does not render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand correctly u want to display this dialog on the first run. so u can keep a boolean value on sharedPreferences and check it when the activity starts. if the user already submitted the e-mail and user id then go on with the normal procedure otherwise display that dialog. when the user submits the id and e-mail dont forget to set the boolean value to true.

Comment: yes but I need a code to show a popup and textbox m newbie in android

Comment: my problem is on start up i'm binding webview also 
  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

so because of that popup does not work properly or sometimes popup appears but webview does not render